# Why are "join" and "meet" named as they are?

Tags: terminology, math-history

In the context of partially ordered sets, why are the words for supremum and infimum "join" and "meet"? I find the nomenclature puzzling, especially since the English words "join" and "meet" are synonyms, but denote opposite concepts when talking about posets.

Does anyone know how these concepts got these names?

[(Cross-posted on HSM)](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/9777/why-are-join-and-meet-named-as-they-are)

Comment: Two street meet at the intersection, and we join together at a family union.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Are you saying they're not synonyms?

Comment: Well, to meet two sets one would consider to arrive to their intersection. To join two sets sounds like to take their union.

Comment: @Berci If two entities "join" each other, then they "meet" each other. Only "join" is also a noun (AFAIK). In my mind, the "join" between two objects is where they touch, which suggests to me intersection if anything. It seems so weird to use two conceptually similar words like this!

Comment: @AsafKaragila What's wrong with two streets joining at an intersection, and family meeting together at a family reunion?

Comment: I always assumed the terminology comes from geometry: two points determine the line *joining* them, while two lines *meet* at a point. But this is purely speculation; maybe ask at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ for an authoritative answer.

Comment: @TheoBendit Two streets, or two things can join to give something new and usually bigger. If you tell me that 2 streets join I imagine something like this: =======>---------. Two streets which combine them to give an avenue, for example.

Comment: @Rahul I quite like that. I don't know if it is *the* answer, but it's a good way of remembering which is which.

Comment: Anyway, it's a really interesting question. I had never thought about that before. And both Asaf's and Rahul's explanations seem incredibly obvious.

Comment: @Dog_69 I agree.  We would hardly say, "The Allegheny and Monongahela rivers join at Pittsburgh, and meet to form the Ohio."

Comment: I think @Rahul is right about the origin of the terms. As for why they're used rather than "supremum" and "infimum", it's probably that people prefer one-syllable words to three-syllable ones, especially if they have to say the words often.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It might be good to get something more than speculation here. Does anyone know if these terms really do come from geometry?

Answer (score -1):

"Join" and "meet" for partially ordered sets could be based on elementary set theory, where you have the union ($\cup$) or intersection ($\cap$) of two or more sets; join $(\vee)$ and meet $(\wedge)$ are their analogues for posets.

Comment: I don't think the Wikipedia article explains why $\vee$ is called *join* and $\wedge$ is called *meet*.

Comment: I can certainly appreciate the symbols involved (and $\cup$ is indeed the join when considering a power set partially ordered by subsets, and similarly $\cap$ is the meet), but I don't see how the names "join" and "meet" relate to set theory.

Comment: I haven't done sets in eons (never mind posets, unless there was a discrete structures class I missed), so my handle on set theory is limited.  If I can find a better answer, I'll update my post.

Comment: @TheoBendit Well, unions tent to be the supremum in set theory while intersections are the infimum. Maybe thinking in that way...

Comment: The answer to this previous MSE question is believable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620325/notation-and-the-name-choice-for-meet-and-join-in-order-theory